# Adding WPF window to Win32 application

Tags: wpf, winapi, interop

I have a monster of a win32 application with GUI based on a mixture of MFC, WTL, user32 and a few other technologies. I need to add another top-level window and I would like to give WPF a chance.

Could you help me identify the steps necessary to host a WPF window in win32 app? Details are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry for giving trite answer, but I can't explain it better than it is explained at MSDN:
[Hosting WPF Content in a Microsoft Win32 Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742522.aspx#hosting_a_wpf_page), [Walkthrough: Hosting a WPF Clock in Win32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970266.aspx). You may also be interested in WPF Documentation samples at [MSDN Code Gallery](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfsamples#migrationandinteroperability), or alternatively look at their [mind-mapped version](http://vivamind.net/maps/detail/70/WPF-Documentation-Samples).

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind if its a top-level window you're after (and not a window embedded within another window) you can simply create a new Window-derived WPF window from managed C++.

I.E., either 1) create a C++/CLI library that references your WPF library and call that from your unmanaged code or 2) add the /clr library setting (not recommended, due to performance implications) and add a reference to your WPF library.  Then simply call:

```
#include <vcclr.h>

gcroot<MyWindow^> newWin = gcnew MyWindow();
newWin->Show();
```